# Can't click my button more once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am just telling before hand that I am not too good with jQuery, I just started learning it yesterday. I am trying to make an interactive guide and the menu at the bottom stays there in the guide. The only thing is that those inputs can't be clicked more than once and when you switch pages, they still can't be clicked.

I know it might be basic, but I am still in learning. Thanks in advance!

```js
$("#menuDiv").on("click", "#menuPresentation", function() {
  $(".videoconference").hide();
  $(".audioconference").hide();
  $(".presentation").fadeIn("slow");
});

$("#menuVideoconference").click(function() {
  $(".presentation").hide();
  $(".audioconference").hide();
  $(".videoconference").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="presentation">
  <div id="menuDiv">
    <img src="img/menu/fond.png" alt="Menu." id="menu">
    <input type="image" src="img/menu/fermeture.png" title="Ferme les appareils en marche et revient à l'écran de début." alt="Bouton de fermeture." class="masterTooltip" id="menuFermeture">
    <input type="image" src="img/menu/presentation.png" title="Vous êtes déjà sur cette option." alt="Bouton présentation." class="masterTooltip" id="menuPresentation">
    <input type="image" src="img/menu/videoconference.png" title="Permet de changer la méthode de diffusion vers la vidéoconférence." alt="Bouton vidéoconférence." class="masterTooltip" id="menuVideoconference">
    <input type="image" src="img/menu/audioconference.png" title="Permet de changer la méthode de diffusion vers l'audioconférence." alt="Bouton audioconférence." class="masterTooltip" id="menuAudioconference">
    <img src="img/menu/micro.png" title="Active ou désactive les microphones." alt="Bouton microphone." class="masterTooltip" id="menuMicro">
    <img src="img/menu/mute.png" title="Enlève le son complétement." alt="Bouton volume mute." class="masterTooltip" id="menuMute">
    <img src="img/menu/moins.png" title="Descend le son." alt="Bouton volume moins." class="masterTooltip" id="menuMoins">
    <img src="img/menu/plus.png" title="Monte le son." alt="Bouton volume plus." class="masterTooltip" id="menuPlus">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="videoconference">
  <div id="menuDiv">
    <img src="img/menu/fond.png" alt="Menu." id="menu">
    <input type="image" src="img/menu/fermeture.png" title="Ferme les appareils en marche et revient à l'écran de début." alt="Bouton de fermeture." class="masterTooltip" id="menuFermeture">
    <input type="image" src="img/menu/presentation.png" title="Permet de changer la méthode de diffusion vers le partage de contenu." alt="Bouton présentation." class="masterTooltip" id="menuPresentation">
    <input type="image" src="img/menu/videoconference.png" title="Vous êtes déjà sur cette option." alt="Bouton vidéoconférence." class="masterTooltip" id="menuVideoconference">
    <input type="image" src="img/menu/audioconference.png" title="Permet de changer la méthode de diffusion vers l'audioconférence." alt="Bouton audioconférence." class="masterTooltip" id="menuAudioconference">
    <img src="img/menu/micro.png" title="Active ou désactive les microphones." alt="Bouton microphone." class="masterTooltip" id="menuMicro">
    <img src="img/menu/mute.png" title="Enlève le son complétement." alt="Bouton volume mute." class="masterTooltip" id="menuMute">
    <img src="img/menu/moins.png" title="Descend le son." alt="Bouton volume moins." class="masterTooltip" id="menuMoins">
    <img src="img/menu/plus.png" title="Monte le son." alt="Bouton volume plus." class="masterTooltip" id="menuPlus">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Change `$("#menuDiv").on` to `$("body").on`

Comment: You've used `menuPresentation` same id to two element.

Comment: @yogendarji there is not only 1 id same.. look around the code. there most of id are same.

Comment: Secondly you cannot have same IDs. **IDs are supposed to be unique.** Your HTML has lot of duplicate IDs.

Comment: What does `right-click > Inspect element > Console`  say ?

Comment: Thanks for the repply, I am testing it now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `menuDiv` two times and you want to show hide contents of them. But when you use the same id more than one time in a page, the jquery considers the 1st one from top and it will attach all your jquery code with that id with that 1st element.

To solve your issue, if you change the `id` attribute to `class` it should work.

Comment: I just saw my error ! thanks for the info. If I want the same element, I should use class !

Comment: can I have a green tick for this answer ? @Pierre-AlexandreGravel

Answer (score 1):

You are using menuDiv id for both presentation as well as for video conference.

Comment: I just saw my error ! thanks for the info. If I want the same element, I should use class !

Comment: **Yes**, If you want to refer same element then you should use class.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code a bit so it was easier to make the menu appear on each page without repeating my HTML 3 times.

```
    <div class="pageCrestron">
    <img src="img/salle2/fond.png" alt="Salle avec table et chaises.">
    <img src="img/salle2/ecran.png" alt="Écran Crestron." id="ecranCrestron">
    <img src="img/menu/fond.png" alt="Menu." id="menu">
    <input type="image" src="img/menu/fermeture.png" title="Ferme les appareils en marche et revient à l'écran de début." alt="Bouton de fermeture." class="masterTooltip" id="menuFermeture">
    <input type="image" src="img/menu/presentation.png" title="Permet de changer la méthode de diffusion vers le partage de contenu." alt="Bouton présentation." class="masterTooltip" id="menuPresentation">
    <input type="image" src="img/menu/videoconference.png" title="Permet de changer la méthode de diffusion vers la vidéoconférence." alt="Bouton vidéoconférence." class="masterTooltip" id="menuVideoconference">
    <input type="image" src="img/menu/audioconference.png" title="Permet de changer la méthode de diffusion vers l'audioconférence." alt="Bouton audioconférence." class="masterTooltip" id="menuAudioconference">
    <img src="img/menu/micro.png" title="Active ou désactive les microphones." alt="Bouton microphone." class="masterTooltip" id="menuMicro">
    <img src="img/menu/mute.png" title="Enlève le son complétement." alt="Bouton volume mute." class="masterTooltip" id="menuMute">
    <img src="img/menu/moins.png" title="Descend le son." alt="Bouton volume moins." class="masterTooltip" id="menuMoins">
    <img src="img/menu/plus.png" title="Monte le son." alt="Bouton volume plus." class="masterTooltip" id="menuPlus">
    <div class="presentation">
        <h2 id="presentationTitle">Points de branchement</h2>
        <img src="img/presentation/boitier1.png" title="Permet de sélectionner le boitier 1. Le bleu signifie qu'il est présentement sélectionné." alt="Boitier de table." class="masterTooltip" id="boitiertable1">
        <img src="img/presentation/boitier2.png" title="Permet de sélectionner le boitier 2. Le gris signifie qu'il n'est présentement pas sélectionné." alt="Boitier de table." class="masterTooltip" id="boitiertable2">
        <img src="img/presentation/aucunsignal.png" title="Indique les possibles périphériques connectés." alt="Aucun signal détecté." class="masterTooltip" id="signal1">
        <img src="img/presentation/aucunsignal.png" title="Indique les possibles périphériques connectés." alt="Aucun signal détecté." class="masterTooltip" id="signal2">
    </div>
    <div class="videoconference">

    </div>
    <div class="audioconference">

    </div>
</div>
```

It makes a bit more sense now. And as suggested in the comment, I used $("body").on for my button and now they work fine !

Thanks to all of you !